# glDrawArrays drawing random point at origin?

Tags: opengl

I have several objects I'm drawing via triangle fans, but once I set my glVertexPointer, and call glDrawArrays, there's always a single point at the origin being drawn that I have not specified, explicitly at least. Below is how I am drawing the scene. The DrawScene function is set to a timer that gets called every 30 ms.

```
    // initialize openGL scene
    InitializeGL(){
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600); 
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); 
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    setUpView() // optional makes a call to glRotate() and glTranslate() in MODELVIEW matrix mode

    drawAxis() //optional method to draw x,y,z axis

    startDrawSceneTimer() // method that just starts the DrawScene timer to 30ms

    }


    DrawScene()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        glEnable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        //poly2 is a 7 point sided polygon, array is pointX, pointY, pointZ of each vertex
        GLfloat poly2 [21] ={ -761.805 , 0.0 , 165.184 , -750.39 , 0.0 , 160.456 ,
        -745.47 , 0.0 , 160.456 , -745.47 , 0.0 , 170.298 , -749.425 , 0.0 , 177.359 ,
        -755.31 , 0.0 , 180.141 , -765.155 , 0.0 , 177.421};
        glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,poly2);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0,21);
        glDisable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
```

There is only suppose to be a single polygon in the bottom left quadrant of the image, similar to a hexagon. The long connection to the origin is the anomaly. My array of verticies "poly2" does not include a vertex(0,0,0) .

Here is an image of what I'm getting:

[image]

When I switch the GL_TRIANGLE_FAN to GL_POINTS, the point at the origin in also drawn. I cannot find anything elsewhere in my code creating the point. I have also tried removing the code for drawing the x,y and z axis but it did not change the problem.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't understand your image. What's wrong with it? Is the white object not supposed to be there? Or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the wrong argument to glDrawArrays. The last parameter should not be the number of floats in the array, rather it should be the vertex count. Since you use x,y,z vertex format you should instead pass 21 / 3 = **7**. As it is now the function call will read past the memory of the array which probably causes the weird behavior you encounter.

See examples such as this: http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=497677